# Show $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For sets $A,B,C$ not equal to $\emptyset$ prove that $$AXB=BXA$$ $$\iff$$ $$A=B$$

Comment: http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/math-proof/truth-tables/truth-tables.html

Comment: Think about the definitions of $U\cup V$ and $U\cap V$. And use that two sets are the same if the first is contained in the second and vice-versa.

Comment: Hi Sebastian Martinez Santos and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: The general way that you show two sets are equal is to show that they are contained in each other. That is, show $$A\cap(B\cup C)\subseteq (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$$and$$(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\subseteq A\cap(B\cup C)$$So take $x\in A\cap(B\cup C)$ and show that $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$, then take $y\in (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$ and show that $y\in A\cap(B\cup C)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Just think about the definitions of $\cap$ and $\cup$ and the following: every element lying in $A$ and $B$ or $C$ is element of $A$ and $B$ or $A$ and $C$ (and reverse).

Answer (score 0):

This is the distributive law for set operations.

http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/level-a/set/set_op_prop.html

This site has list of set operations and some proofs which will show you one way to do this.